# Fill list from Xml file using Linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list

I am trying to fill a list of clients from an xml file using linq, but i always get this null exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Here is my code, starting with the Client class:

```
public class Client
{
    // Personne Physique
    public string IdClient { get; set; }
    public string NomClient { get; set; }
    public string PrenomClient { get; set; }
    public Client(){}
}
```

The code to fill the list:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(pathXml);
List<Client> lc = doc.Descendants("Anzeige")
                     .FirstOrDefault()
                     .Descendants("Kunde")
                     .Select(p => new Client()
                     {
                         IdClient = p.Element("KundNr").Value,
                         NomClient = p.Element("Nachname").Value,
                         PrenomClient = p.Element("Vorname").Value
                     }).ToList<Client>();
```

The xml file looks like this:

```
<Anzeige>
  <Kunde>
     <KundNr>111</KundNr>
     <Nachname>111</Nachname>
     <Vorname>111</Vorname> 
  </Kunde>
</Anzeige>
```

Help please! I am pressed by time.

Comment: you have to put Attribute (XmlElement) over the property 
like [XmlAttribute("KundNr")] over IdClient and so on

Comment: could you write me an example please, I didn't go it very well , thank you

Comment: ok let me do it on my system first.

Comment: Why was the 3rd edit approved?

Comment: so , any suggestions please?

Comment: @user1503496 just verified - your code works fine and returns one client for given xml. Please, provide xml which gives you error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will be fine for the sample Xml you have posted.
However you are not handling some scenarios where your code will break. For example:

- An Xml document with no `<Anzeige>` node will cause a null exception
  in `doc.Descendants("Anzeige").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Kunde")`
  as the result from `FirstOrDefault()` will be null.
- An Xml document where one of the `<Kunde>` nodes doesn't have one of
  the value nodes will also cause an exception. For example if there is
  no `<Vorname>` value then this piece of code will throw an exception
  `p.Element("Vorname").Value`

You can tweak a bit your code to handle these scenarios.

**Edit:** You can use `Elements` instead of `Descendants` to force an xml where the Anzeige nodes come directly after the root and Kunde are direct childs of Anzeige. I have also edited my answer to take advantage of the cast operators that you can use directly on an XElement. This way `(int?) p.Element("KundNr")` returns either an `int` or `null` value if the node doesn't exist. Combined with `??` operator its a clean way to read the value. The cast will work with string values and basic value types like `int` or `decimal`. (Just for the purpose of demonstrating this I changed `IdClient` to an `int`)

You can still have an error if you try to convert to `int?` and the node value is something that cannot be converted on an `int` like `"ABC"`. However you had all fields as strings so that shouldn't be a problem for you:

```
var clients = doc.Descendants("Anzeige").Descendants("Kunde").Select(p => new Client()
{
    IdClient = (int?) p.Element("KundNr") ?? -1,
    NomClient = (string) p.Element("Nachname") ?? String.Empty,
    PrenomClient = (string) p.Element("Vorname") ?? String.Empty
}).ToList();
```

I have put together a small console application testing a few sample xmls:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<Anzeige>
                <Kunde>
                    <KundNr>111</KundNr>
                    <Nachname>111</Nachname>
                    <Vorname>111</Vorname> 
                </Kunde>
                <Kunde>
                    <KundNr>222</KundNr>                            
                    <Nachname>222</Nachname>
                    <Vorname>222</Vorname> 
                </Kunde>
            </Anzeige>");
    ExtractClients(doc);

    var docWithMissingValues = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<Anzeige>
                <Kunde>
                    <KundNr>111</KundNr>
                    <Vorname>111</Vorname> 
                </Kunde>
                <Kunde>
                    <KundNr>222</KundNr>                            
                    <Nachname>222</Nachname>
                </Kunde>
                <Kunde>
                </Kunde>
            </Anzeige>");
    ExtractClients(docWithMissingValues);

    var docWithoutAnzeigeNode = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<AnotherNode>
                <Kunde>
                    <KundNr>111</KundNr>
                    <Vorname>111</Vorname> 
                </Kunde>
            </AnotherNode>");
    ExtractClients(docWithoutAnzeigeNode);

    var docWithoutKundeNodes = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<Anzeige>
                <OtherNode></OtherNode>
            </Anzeige>");
    ExtractClients(docWithoutKundeNodes);

    var emptyDoc = new XDocument();
    ExtractClients(emptyDoc);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ExtractClients(XDocument doc)
{
    var clients = doc.Descendants("Anzeige").Descendants("Kunde").Select(p => new Client()
    {
        //You can manually get the value like this:
        //IdClient = p.Element("KundNr") != null ? p.Element("KundNr").Value : String.Empty,
        //NomClient = p.Element("Nachname") != null ? p.Element("Nachname").Value : String.Empty,
        //PrenomClient = p.Element("Vorname") != null ? p.Element("Vorname").Value : String.Empty

        //Or directly cast the node value to the type (value types or strings) required like:
        IdClient = (int?) p.Element("KundNr") ?? -1,
        NomClient = (string) p.Element("Nachname") ?? String.Empty,
        PrenomClient = (string) p.Element("Vorname") ?? String.Empty
    }).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", client.IdClient, client.NomClient, client.PrenomClient);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-',30));
}

public class Client
{
    // Personne Physique
    public int IdClient { get; set; }
    public string NomClient { get; set; }
    public string PrenomClient { get; set; }
    public Client() { }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to make a !=null control on "ar clients = doc.Descendants("Anzeige").Descendants("Kunde").Select(p => new Client()" , how can i do it, thx

Comment: @user1503496 I have added some more information to my answer. Regarding nulls there, please take a look at the samples that I've added. You will notice that chaining `Descendants` (or even `Elements`) calls handles nicely scenarios where there are no results, ending in an empty client list. (In fact, the last 3 tests will end up in an empty clients list)